# ZF2 - ZF1 - database

Tags: zend-framework2

I just switched from ZF1 to ZF2 and I'm missing a few features or I#M just not able to find them. For example in ZF1 I was able to define references between tables extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` or I was able to get e.g. images for a tag using the `find<XYZ>Via<xyz>()`method. Is there something similar in ZF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing similar like this in ZF2.

With ZF2, the maintainers of `Zend\Db` have taken a step back as far as ORM-Functionalities are concerned. You still have the implementation of `Zend\Db\TableGateway` but there is no longer any more magic happening than that.

However, there are Modules / Technologies out there, that do the Job better than `Zend_Db` ever did. Namely you'd want to be looking into [**Doctrine**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). All Doctrine-Functionalities are available via [`DoctrineModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) and [`DoctrineORMModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule).